# Search using Secondary Index and range on Timeuuid column changes the order of range search

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-3.0

My table schema is as follows :-

```
create table test ( 
 devicename text, 
 date text,
 id timeuuid,
 code text,
 flag int,
 primary key (devicename, date, id)
) with clustering order by ( date desc , id desc )

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX code_idx ON test (code) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer',
'case_sensitive': 'false' };
```

Now my select Query is :-

```
select * from test where devicename = 'ABC' 
and id > minTimeuuid('2017-08-25 00:00:00') and id < maxTimeuuid('2017-08-25 23:59:59') allow filtering;
```

It gives result. Now if I want to use Secondary Index , the order of search reverses :-

```
Select * from test where devicename = 'ABC' 
and id > minTimeuuid('2017-08-25 00:00:00') and id < maxTimeuuid('2017-08-25 23:59:59')
and code like '%25%' allow filtering;
```

The above code gives 0 result whereas when I change the order of timeuuid column in search , it gives correct result like this :-

```
Select * from test where devicename = 'ABC' 
and id < minTimeuuid('2017-08-25 00:00:00') and id > maxTimeuuid('2017-08-25 23:59:59')
and code like '%25%' allow filtering;
```

My table schema is still unchanged i.e. it shows id is in descending order , then why the search order changes when I'am using secondary Index column in select . Please suggest where I'am going wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Start with making a new table for each query you want to make and update them all on inserts/updates, then see if you can combine them. Allow filtering is meant for debugging or one off queries. It will break a real cluster under load. It is _possible_ in some scenarios to use it effectively but that case is mostly around bulk reading scenarios like spark jobs. Id recommend going through data modeling lessons at https://academy.datastax.com/courses.

Comment: Hi @ChrisLohfink , I have seen the courses . My only doubt is why using Index column in search changes the sign of id column. Although the result set remains the same but why do I have to use inverted signs in range query.